H1B visa: Received royalties for an academic book published by the UK-based publisher
I am an Indian citizen and have been working as a Research Scientist on an H1B (lottery exempt) visa at a US university since November 2023. Before this, I was on a J-1 visa (Research Scholar) at a national lab in the US starting in 2018.
During my time on the J-1 visa, I authored five books in my research area. Four of these books were published by a UK-based publisher in December 2023 (although the work was completed before my H1B visa term began), and the fifth book was published by a US-based publisher in March 2024.
Recently, I received royalties via wire transfer for the four books published by the UK-based publisher. The publisher informed me that "We are required by the UK Tax Authority to deduct 20% Income Tax at source unless a double tax clearance has been approved." As a result, the royalties I received had already been taxed at 20% in the UK.
I would like to know if I need to pay taxes in the US on these royalties. If so, how should I report this income to the IRS? If not, do I still need to inform IRS about these royalties?
I have not yet received royalties from the US-based publisher for my fifth book. However, when I do, what kind of tax form can I expect from the US-based publisher? Additionally, is receiving such income legal considering my current H1B visa status?
Regards,
RD


I would like to know if I need to pay taxes in the US on these royalties.

As I mentioned in the nearly identical cross-posted question - the US taxes worldwide income. So yes, you do need to pay taxes in the US on these royalties.

If so, how should I report this income to the IRS?

This goes on the Schedule E of your Federal tax return (form 1040). The UK tax paid goes on the form 1116 included in your Federal tax return.

I have not yet received royalties from the US-based publisher for my fifth book. However, when I do, what kind of tax form can I expect from the US-based publisher?

Form 1099-MISC.

Additionally, is receiving such income legal considering my current H1B visa status?

There are no US visas that have any restrictions on receiving income. There are plenty of visas which have restrictions on earning income, which is not the same. In any case, you've already received the income, legal or not you still need to pay your taxes.

Thanks! Very useful. If I report the 20% UK tax on Form 1116, how much more tax would I have to pay in the US? I understand I need to report the income and UK tax regardless.

@r2d2 there are some calculations on form 1116, you can follow the instructions. You should also consider the Anglo-American tax treaty which may affect how much you owe in the UK.
